# Slider Revolution - Background Image Link not clicking in Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, revolution-slider

We are using revolution slider for the slideshow on the home page. The links to buy tickets works in firefox, but the links are not clickable in chrome.

https://havenac.com

I turned off all plugins and turned them on one by one to test for a plugin conflict. As far as I can tell there is not a plugin conflict.

I created a blank page template here and hard coded the wp-head.php to test for css or javascript conflicts by removing each script one by one. What I found is that when I remove the style.css for the theme, that the links in the slider begin to work. So I am assuming there is something in that file conflicting with the revolution slider code. Here is that test page:

https://havenac.com/dj-battle/

I cannot tell what part of the css is causing the conflict. I am thinking maybe it is z levels or fancybox css. Or maybe chrome is rendering the css differently somehow.

Here is the line of code I am removing from the wp-head.php that is making it work.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='base-style-css'  href='https://havenac.com/wp-content/themes/havennightclubgo/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the many div layers under `.tp-parallax-wrap`, specifically `.tp-caption slidelink` has an inline style of `max-height: 1px`. I believe this is what causes the problem. I added a test class in the browser inspector with a `max-height: 100% !important` which fixed the issue.

I wouldn't use the !important style that I used. But the div that causes your problem has 1px height, which gives the inner `a` tag a 1px height as well. Try this out and see if this fixes your issue!

Comment: Woo! Let me check that out.

Comment: I am definitely able to see what you found with the 1px height and added a test class in the browser inspector to make it work.

I added the `.tp-caption slidelink` style to my style.css but it did not work, even with `!important`. I also tested adding it to the revolution slider css area within the plugin settings. Neither worked. Next I am going to try to download the revolution slider plugin files to see if I can find that inline style.

Comment: Have you tried including the changes to the slider plugin's stylesheet?

Comment: Just need to find what defines the max-height as 1px in this snippet `<div class="tp-caption slidelink" style="cursor: pointer;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: 60;visibility: inherit;transition: none;line-height: 17px;border-width: 0px;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;letter-spacing: 0px;font-weight: 400;font-size: 13px;white-space: nowrap;min-height: 0px;min-width: 0px;max-height: 1px;max-width: none;opacity: 1;transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;" data-x="center" data-y="center" data-basealign="slide" data-start="0"></div>`

Comment: I'm guessing it's defined by a javascript, so you might want to look into the js scripts and see where it's defined. What plugin is it?

Comment: Firefox shows this snippet as having a max-height of 700599px, so that is why I am able to click in firefox.

Comment: Revolution Slider - I just downloaded all the files.

Comment: Figured it out! There is a purple button for Global Styles Editor where we could edit the dynamic styles. Added the code `.tp-caption  { max-height: 600px;}` and all was solved. Thank you for your help